# Getting Same Exinterface orientation irrespective of which ever orientation I capture a picture?

Tags: android, camera, orientation, surfaceview

I am using Camera api with surface view to capture images.I have set the application orientation to portrait in manifest file. I have the following code

```
 ExifInterface exif = null;
 int a = 0;

 try {
  exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

 if (exif != null) {
  a = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
      ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

  try {
   exif.saveAttributes();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

> But i got the same orientation value(value of a) which is irrespective
>   of the phone orientation.

How do I get the different orientation values for portrait and landscape?

Comment: `(value of a)`. Well tell the value!

Comment: `imagePath`. Sorry but we cannot see what that path has to do with an image taken.

Comment: value of a is different for each phones and image path is a local image path.

Comment: As you are not answering my questions i can not help you.

Comment: `I have set the application orientation to portrait in manifest file`.

Comment: value of a is diffrent  for different phones.on some evices it may 0 in some other it may 6 etc

Comment: image path is some local image path

Comment: `image path is some local image path` You already told that. Better give the asked info instead.